# Disable Firefox 4.x Tab Swithing Keyboard Shortcut CTRL-`

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Version 4.x of Firefox overrides one of my keyboard shortcuts [CTRL-`]. I really would like to disable it. Please post if you know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [keyconfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/) extension (*keyconfig.xpi*); you will be able to re-define/enable/disable and create new key mappings via GUI.

Don't know, why its author doesn't update it at addons.mozilla.org, though. However, he provides up to date version in his homepage (compatible with ff 4).